# What version of JPA am I using?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

in a apache-tomcat-8.0.41 web service.

In this link they say "Hibernate EntityManager implements the programming interfaces and lifecycle rules as defined by the JPA 2.0 specification" 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/

But it's for the 3.6 version. 
It's the same for 5.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read the docs of the version you are using. As for hibernate and JPA compatibility see here: [Hibernate releases](http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/)

Hibernate 5.1 docs: [Hibernate 5.1 docs](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.1/)

Answer (score 3):

`hibernate-jpamodelgen` is neither JPA nor hibernate. It is a maven plugin which helps to use JPA by auto-generating classes.

For example, if you have a class named `User`, `hibernate-jpamodelgen` will create a class `User_` that contains fields which are very useful when using the criteria API.

For your JPA version, you should look at another dependency. If you have this one, then you are using JPA > 2.0

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've edited the question with the other dependencies.

Comment: Don't have any JPA jar in my pom.xml

Comment: @Gaetano As far as I can see in this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa), Hibernate 5.1 is compatible with JPA 2.1

Comment: JPA is a specification and not a library. I would recommend you explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: The question is: what specification of JPA does hibernate 5.1 implements.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to discover what version you are using is to execute the maven command:

`mvn dependency:tree`

Here I can see I'm running JPA 2.2.3:

```
> mvn depedency:tree
...
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile <!-- JPA
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.4.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.22:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.22:compile
...
```